# How do I get to the hotfix, if the link is broken?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7

I've got a problem with my IIS 7, on a Windows 2008 R2 Server, not working for some of our users. (All using IE 10; it's a known issue.) I've learned that there's a hotfix, I've gone to Microsoft's website to try and get it. They had me fill out some info, with my email address, to get a link sent to me via email, so that I could get the fix via a link in the email. I've received the email, and then copied and pasted the link into my browser.

And it went no where. Error 404.

So, how do I get to a link to a hotfix, when that link is broken?

Comment: Contact your Microsoft support representative? (seriously - what is Server Fault supposed to do about a 404 on Microsoft's servers?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it again, but if the link is truly not working then you can call MS support and they will give you free hotfix support directly.

You can contact them directly by looking here:

http://smallbusiness.support.microsoft.com/en-us/contact

That's the fastest way I've found to contact them, either via chat or phone.

You can also call the old IT Pro line:  (800) 936-4900

Hotfix support is always free, so they should be able to assist.